# indexing where conditions are true in an array, then make into new variable

Tags: matlab

Matlab.

Suppose i have the following:

```
a=randi(675,2000,1);
```

where `"a"` is a `2000x1` array of random integers with the highest one being `675`.  I would like to find all values greater than `150` and put them (however many) into a new array "b".
What I have tried so far: letting `b=(a>150)`, this gives me a logical array, not what i want.
 I tried `[row,col]=find(a>150)`, this gives me the locations where the condition is true, but how do I then make a new variable "b" out of that?

Thank You.

Comment: Google "matrix indexing in matlab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write :

```
b=a(a>150);
```

Comment: First off thank you.  Second, how does what you wrote change the logical array (b=a>150) into the one with the actual values ? how does that extra "a" in there accomplish this?

Comment: @MisterOH You should [read this article](https://ch.mathworks.com/de/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) about matrix indexing in matlab. `a>150`, only create the logical index (an array composed only of `0` and `1`) but do not retrieve the value > 150 contained in the array a.